# How to print the contents of a file using linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

EDIT: Never mind i actually did it.

So as i said in the title im trying to print out the contents of the file using linked lists.
Basically we are given a txt file to read and we should print out certain stuff but for now step one for me in this exercise is to try read and print out the contents of the txt file.

The file is:

```
Mi illumino di immenso
Illumino di immenso
Di immenso
IMMENSO
```

This is what i have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

typedef struct node
{
    char *str;
    struct node* next;

}node;
node *createlist(FILE *file)
{

    node *tmp=NULL;
    node *head=NULL;
    node* p=NULL;
    char buffer[N+3];

    file=fopen("file","r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file:");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",buffer)!=EOF)
    {
        tmp=malloc(sizeof(node*));
        tmp->str=malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));
        tmp->next=NULL;
        if(tmp==NULL)
        {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(tmp->str == NULL)
        {
            printf("Allocation error");
            exit(2);
        }
        strcpy(tmp->str,buffer);
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            p=head;
            while(p->next !=NULL)
            {
                p=p->next;
            }
            p->next=tmp;
        }


    }


    return head;
}

void printfile(node *head)
{
    node* tmp=head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ",tmp->str);
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    node *head=NULL;

    head=createlist(file);
    printfile(head);


    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that while it prints only the first word it keeps printing random symbols after that infinitely. And i cant seem to figure out what causes this.
Any idea on how i might fix it?

Comment: How is `head=createlist(buffer);` ever going to use the _previous_ line in the list?

Comment: @DavisHerring well. The idea i had in mind when i implemented this was that i read a word from the file, store it the buffer send it to the function and process from there. So im afraid i dont understand the question. I apologize but im fairly new in the programming part

Comment: The statement `if(head==NULL)` is not meaningful, because it will always be true.

Comment: @SeverjanLici: If `head` is supposed to hold the entire list, but each value is a function only of `buffer`, you're definitely going to lose track of all existing data each iteration.  (`head` in `createlist` is an unrelated variable, as Andreas hints.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I think it does make sense at least for the first time(according to a video) because while we create a node using the tmp we check if the head is empty or not. If it is we simply use the node tmp as the starting node else if it is already a list we add the tmp node at the end. At least thats how i see it and tried to implement

Comment: @DavisHerring and doesnt the function return the head at the very end to be used in the main?

Comment: Please describe in your own words what the function `createList` is supposed to do. Is it supposed to create a new linked list with exactly one element? Or is it supposed to add a new node to a (possibly) already existing linked list? The name of the function and its parameters imply the former, but the latter would be more useful for solving the assignment.

Comment: @SeverjanLici: Of course `createlist` returns the list, but not "to be used in the main" since every iteration except the last throws away that value.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel So how i see it (as i said i saw how one guy did it in a video) but my interpretation of the createlist would be: First we scan in the main the file and get the buffer which is passed to the function. The function receives it and stores it into the tmp node which is just a node not a list. we check to see if the head list is empty or not. if it is which initially it is we put the tmp node as the starting node. then since head is no longer NULL we add a node to it every iteration from the while untill we reach EOF. At least thats how i see it

Comment: @DavisHerring Then can i ask how you suggest i fix the error?

Comment: @DavisHerring Never mind i actually did it xd. I will upload it in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your most recent edit, one issue is that the function call

```
head=createlist(file);
```

does not make sense, because `file` is not initialized. This means that it contains an indeterminate value. Since you open the file inside the function `createlist`, it does not make sense that the function `main` passes a `FILE *` parameter to `createlist`. It would make more sense to remove that parameter or maybe to change the parameter to pass the name of the file.

Another issue is that in the function `createlist`, it does not make sense that you write

```
if(tmp==NULL)
{
    printf("Allocation error");
    exit(1);
}
```

only after already having dereferenced `tmp` in the following line:

```
tmp->str=malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

You should first check whether `tmp` is `NULL` and only then dereference it, otherwise your program will likely crash if `tmp` is indeed `NULL`.

Another issue is that the line

```
tmp=malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
tmp=malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Also, it is generally considered good practice to `free` the memory that you allocated, in order to prevent a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). It is also considered good practice to close a file when you no longer need it, using the function `fclose`.